# Restrict image to be zoom out from its initial point using Angular ngx-panzoom library

Tags: angular

We are having a zoom in and zoom out button and we want to restrict the image to zoom out from its initial state.

We have tried the below trials but nothing worked (Here gridElement is a view child of a div in HTML):

```
zoom(zoomIn:boolean) : void {
        if (zoomIn)
            this.panZoomAPI.zoomIn();
        else {
            this.panZoomConfig.neutralZoomLevel
            let height = this.gridElement.nativeElement.clientHeight;
            const width = this.gridElement.nativeElement.clientWidth;
            height = 1500 * height / width;
            
            if (height < this.gridElement.nativeElement.clientHeight)
                this.panZoomAPI.zoomOut();
            else {
                this.panZoomConfig.initialZoomLevel = 0;
                //this.panZoomConfig.initialZoomToFit.y = 0;
                //this.panZoomConfig.initialZoomToFit.width = 1500;
                //this.panZoomConfig.initialZoomToFit.height = height;
            }
            //this.panZoomAPI.zoomOut();
        }
    }
```

We are using ngx-panzoom package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this; On my code for unknown reason its prevent the element from zooming-out:

```
  private panZoomConfigOptions: PanZoomConfigOptions = { 
  freeMouseWheel: false,
  zoomStepDuration: 0.5, 
  zoomOnDoubleClick: false, 
  friction: 10, 
  keepInBounds: true 
  }; 
  public panZoomConfig: PanZoomConfig = new PanZoomConfig(this.panZoomConfigOptions);
```